# How to get username after logged in?.I am trying with MSAL (@azure/msal-angular) for Azure Signin

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying with MSAL (@azure/msal-angular) for Azure Signin and new to angular .I need  to get  username after logged in and display it in UI.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve the user from [`MsalService`](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/msal-angular/classes/_msal_service_.msalservice.html), for example with:

```js
const accountInfo: AccountInfo | null = this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount();
```

It's recommended to wait until the authentication process is complete before you invoke this. This can be done by checking `MsalBroadcastService`:

```js
const account: Observable<AccountInfo | null> = this.msalBroadcastService
    .inProgress$
    .pipe(
        filter(status => status == InteractionStatus.None),
        map(() => {
            const instance: IPublicClientApplication = this.msalService.instance;
            const activeAccount: AccountInfo | null = instance.getActiveAccount();
            const accounts: AccountInfo[] = instance.getAllAccounts();
            if (activeAccount != null) return activeAccount;
            if (accounts.length > 0) {
                const [firstAccount] = accounts;
                instance.setActiveAccount(firstAccount);
                return firstAccount;
            }
            return null;
        })
    );
  
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `myMSALObj.getAccount().userName` to get userName.

```
function showWelcomeMessage() {
    var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
    divWelcome.innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + myMSALObj.getAccount().userName + " to Microsoft Graph API";
    var loginbutton = document.getElementById('SignIn');
    loginbutton.innerHTML = 'Sign Out';
    loginbutton.setAttribute('onclick', 'signOut();');
}
```

For more details, see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/ec094d89bd98fe9fd11b49d254bee3c6c7cdd105/samples/msal-core-samples/UnifiedCacheTestApp/MSAL.html#L103).

Comment: Could you please share more details about your code? There is an [example](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/ec094d89bd98fe9fd11b49d254bee3c6c7cdd105) in my reply.

Comment: Thank you so much I did much more R & D . Your answer helped.It works now

Comment: this doesnt answer where the msal object or auth service comes from ...

Comment: Answer is deprecated can someone please reopen